# How to allow multiple connections to a slow Django view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a simple, fairly slow view function in django that looks like this:

```
def example_view(request):
    context = external_api_call_that_takes_a_long_time_to_return()
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

When I access the view from two tabs, however, it only runs one of these view functions at a time. The first one takes 10 seconds to load, the second one 10 seconds after that.

How do I let my server generate those views concurrently?

Comment: @gipsy 's approach with adding more workers is definitely the quickest way to do it but it's not a perfect solution for when you get a lot of users. In this case, something like a NodeJS server can be great to handle the requests, since most of what you're doing is just waiting for a HTTP response. This does mean that your django view will now be asynchronous, though, which will impact how users interact with the view.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of options for you are

1. Run multiple instances of your app behind a load balancer. For
   example reverse proxy using nginx to say two instances of your app
   running at two different ports.
2. Use gunicorn to launch your django app with more than one worker.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/